# Java EWS API - Read email from exchange - Comparable options

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using Java EWS API to connect my application to MS Exchange and read user email requests. These requests are then processed through the system workflow. The amount of emails in a day is limited to 50 so the overall volume is less. However I am looking at an efficient and reliable mechanism to read from exchange server using EWS API. Also note that once the email is processed we move it to sub folders so Inbox only has the unprocessed requests

Currently as I understand the following schemes are used to connect to Exchange server and perform various operations on the mailbox.

1. Polling - Connect to Exchange using the standard Exchange Service interface; find all new emails and process them in sequence. The client has better control over failures and synchronization between the reads and moving to processed folders. On the downside the experience isn’t real time and connections are made to exchange even if there isn’t any activity.
2. Pull Notifications - This method is almost identical to previous one, subscribe to pull notifications using an interval and read emails from Inbox whenever the timer event occurs. Pros and cons are similar to approach 1.
3. Push Notifications - Here the clients subscribe to exchange server for receiving push notifications by registering themselves to particular events and define a callback mechanism (Client Web service) to receive notifications. On the upside the notifications are near real time and connections are made only when there are events. On the downside I see that subscriptions and watermark needs to be managed on the client side so that events aren’t lost. Not sure if this is still a reliable approach as what happens to messages that are already in the inbox before establishing a subscription; will those events be replayed when server starts? It’s not clear.
4. Streaming Subscription - Clients establish a Streaming connection and then keep it open for a maximum of 30 min with the server and during this time exchange will notify any registered events. Once the connection dies there is an ability to restore it so that the subscription stays alive. It seemed like the best approach until I started hearing that an additional steps to Sync folder items and maintain sync state; is required at regular intervals so that events are not missed from connect/disconnect.

Looking at my needs (read emails from exchange server reliably) and analysis of various options I feel that approach 1 is simple and more reliable as it gives better control over the entire process. But at the same time I wanted to circle with others who are familiar with the API to correct me if my understanding of the framework in terms of pros and cons is wrong.

I am open for any suggestions from the group in order to make this better as the intent is to not miss any email.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the code simplicity of option 1. If you connect once a minute the load is very low (just a FindItem call returning nothing) and the users experience it as almost instantaneous.

You're are only handling 50 a day max so the wish to be 'instantaneous' is a bit contradictory (if the user only does that many updates he surely can wait  a minute).

Comment: I agree with you Jan. The real time need was for the business users to see the workflow kicked off soon after the email is sent and then be able to track the progress in the dashboard. But I guess its meaningful to settle down for a small delay to gain reliability.